# Geb Firefox Driver: why my test runs twice?

Tags: firefox, grails, selenium-webdriver, grails-2.0, geb

Sorry for all this code, but I don't have a clue what's making my issue, so here it goes.

I configured the geb plugin to run functional tests with JUnit. So I have in my **buildConfig.groovy**:

```
def seleniumVersion = "2.29.0"
def gebVersion = "0.7.0"

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5'

    provided('com.oracle:oracle:11.1.0.7.0')
    provided('com.oracle:i18n:10.2.0.5')


    test ("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion") {
        export = false
    }
    test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"){ 
        excludes "commons-io"
        export = false
    }
    test ("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:$seleniumVersion") {
        export = false
    }

    test ("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion") {
        export = false
    }
    test ("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:$seleniumVersion") {
        export = false
    } 

    test ("org.codehaus.geb:geb-junit4:$gebVersion") {
        export = false
    }

}

plugins {
  build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion") {
  export = false
  excludes 'svn'
  }
  compile (":hibernate:$grailsVersion") {
  export = false
  excludes 'svn'
  }

  build (":release:2.0.0") {
  excludes 'commons-io','http-builder'
  export = false
  }

   compile(":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3") { excludes 'svn' }
   compile(":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6")

   compile (":remote-control:1.3") {
  export = false
   }

   test(":geb:$gebVersion") {
     export = false
   }
}
```

And I have a **GebConfig.groovy** in my conf folder:

```
driver = {
//def driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
//driver.javascriptEnabled = true
//driver
def driver = new FirefoxDriver()
driver
} 

environments {
   // run as “grails -Dgeb.env=chrome test-app”
   // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
   chrome {
     driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
   }

   // run as “grails -Dgeb.env=firefox test-app”
   // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver
   firefox {
    driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
  }
}
```

I have a functional test for the login:

```
class LoginTests extends GebReportingTest {


    @Test
    void login() {
        to LoginPage
        at LoginPage

        username = "SERGIO"
        password = "SERGIO"

        loginButton.click()

        assert at(IndexPage)

        link.click()

    }

}
```

And this are my two pages:

```
class LoginPage extends Page {

    static url = "login/auth"

    static at = {
        title ==~ /Efetuar Login/
    }

    static content = {
        loginForm { $("form", id: "loginForm") }
        username { $("input", type:"text", id:"username") }
        password { $("input", type:"password", id:"password") }
        loginButton{ $("input", type:"submit", id:"submit") }
    }

}

class IndexPage extends Page {

    static at = {
        title ==~ /Security Service Index View/
    }

    static content = {
        description { $('h1') }
        link { $('a') } 
    }

}
```

For some reason my functional test run twice and don't matter how I start this:

```
grails test-app :functional

grails test-app -functional
```

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your problem but why do you need the dependency on selenium-remote-driver? Also, can you explain what do you mean by saying that your test run twice? Twice in FF? Which Grails version are you using? What other plugins do you have installed?

Comment: I edited the list of plugins installed. I just copied the selenium dependencies from an example, so the remote came from that :)

Comment: By running twice, I mean that the functional tests run twice (appears in console "running test 1" twice, and FF do his work two times too.

Comment: Well, removing the remote dependency didn't change anything.

Comment: I'll ask again as you haven't responded - Which Grails version are you using? What other grails plugins do you have installed? If You're on Grails 2.0+ you should probably use Geb 0.7.2 or even 0.9.0-RC-1 which will soon be released as 0.9.0 as there are no issues with it.

Comment: Grails 2.0.4, and I answered the plugins (code edited in the question). Already tried with Geb 0.9.0 and got the same result.

Comment: Any chance for a reproducible sample posted to github for example? I could run it locally and see if I'm hitting the same issue and analyse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Geb plugin isn't fully compatible with Grails 2.3.x . For some reason tests get executed twice after upgrading to Geb plugin 0.9.2 .

I believe this problem is related to https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10552 and changes made as part of https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6352 .

In Grails 2.3.x+, the GrailsSpecTestType takes care of both Junit and Spock tests:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bce298f0/grails-test/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/test/spock/GrailsSpecTestType.groovy#L33

It looks like the Geb plugin is adding the deprecated JUnit4GrailsTestType to execution:
https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/584738cb/integration/geb-grails/scripts/_Events.groovy#L60-L67

This is why functional tests get executed twice.

This is how I got around the problem in Geb 0.9.2 / 0.9.3 versions.

```
grails test-app functional:spock
```

It looks like Geb version 0.9.1 didn't execute the tests twice.

The difference seems to be caused by this commit:
https://github.com/geb/geb/commit/9c71e820

You should also be aware that you shouldn't have the Spock plugin installed in Grails 2.3.x/2.4.x .

Comment: This problem has already been reported to Geb Jira: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-314

Answer (score 0):

Hi Not Much of a Selenium WebDriver on Ruby but It seems to be that you are starting Firefox twice as such the test runs in two instances

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because my tests run twice in sequence, and I didn't control the start of FF.