# Grails test cases run twice when I execute grails test-app

Tags: grails, spock

I am using Spock plug-in in my grails-2.3.4 application for automated unit and integration tests. When I run grails test-app, all the test cases run two times.  Also in test report, every spec file is listed twice. As the application grew, number of test cases also grew, and all of them run twice. This takes double time to execute all of the test cases while development and deploying through Jenkins. Can anyone help me fix it (any help will be appreciated)?

Comment: This link will helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404892/geb-firefox-driver-why-my-test-runs-twice

Answer (score 3):

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.4/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html -> Spock included by default

> You no longer need to add the Spock plugin to your projects. Simply
>   create Spock specifications as before and they will be run as unit
>   tests. In fact, don't install the Spock plugin, otherwise your
>   specifications will run twice [...].